# What are elements of an array in C initialized to after making the array?

Tags: c, arrays

So when I create an array in the programming language c, what are all of the elements initially initialized to? For instance,

```
char array[5];
```

Creates an array with 5 elements. What are the elements initially? I printed the elements out, but it seemed to be random, so are they just created randomly, or is there a method to how they are made?

Comment: Where did you declare your array? In block scope? In file scope?

Comment: "I printed the elements out, but it seemed to be random" --> _posting_ that code and its output is more useful than _describing_ the code and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What are the elements initially" will depend on where and how your array is defined.

A automatic array defined in block scope will contain garbage. Meanwhile, a static array will be initialized with zeros.

```
char a[5]; /* zeros */

int main()
{
  static char b[5]; /* zeros */

  char c[5]; /* garbage */
}
```

If the array is declared as a struct member, then the above rules apply to the definition of the containing struct object.

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you initialize them.

- Global : All the values in the array will be 0
- Local : The values will be some garbage value.Its random.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of an uninitialized array (or any uninitialized object) are undetermined. Accessing them invokes Undefined Behaviour.

```
char a[5], b[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, c[5] = {42};
printf("%d\n", a[1]); // UB
printf("%d\n", b[1]); // 2
printf("%d\n", c[1]); // 0
```

Note that `static` objects or global scope objects have a default zero initialization.

Comment: Hmmm Is there not a UB exception to uninitialized `unsigned char []`?  Like `unsigned char uc[1]; printf("%u\n", uc[0]*0);` is OK?

Comment: I believe there is @chux; I'm on my phone, can't check the Standard at the moment.